# How i can echo this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array :

```
array(2) {
    ["ok"]=> bool(true)
    ["result"]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> int(115133849)
        ["first_name"]=> string(5) "drugs"
        ["username"]=> string(7) "darubot"
    }
}
```

I wanna echo only '115133849'. How i can? I try loop but don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
$yourArray["result"]["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that array into a variable for example `$arrayVar` now print like this:

```
echo $arrayVar["result"]["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming array name is $array with many elements

```
<?php
     $array = array( "ok" => "true",
                     "result" => array("id" => 115133849,
                                       "first_name" => "drugs",
                                       "username" => "darubot"
                                       )  
     );

     echo $array["result"]["id"];
```